# C# Compare 2 List Object and create a third

Tags: c#, linq

I have this class:

```
public class Bills
{
    public int Denom;
    public int NumberItems;
}
```

And two list of this class:

```
ListA:
 Denom:20
 NumberItems:1

ListB:
 Denom:20
 NumberItems:4,
 Denom:50
 NumberItems:2
```

How can I do a LINQ for made a third list whith the diference of those two list:

```
ListC:
 Denom:20
 NumberItems:3
 Denom:50
 NumberItems:2
```

I know this can be made with foreach but I think there is a better way.

Elemts in ListA will always be in ListB with the same or smaller NumberItems, but elemts in ListB possible not in ListA; no Denom repeated in each List

Here is the foreach that works for me:

```
        List<Bills> ListC = new List<Bills>();

        foreach (var denomB in ListB) 
        {
            bool isInListA = false;

            foreach (var denomA in ListA) 
            {
                if (denomB.Value == denomA.Value)
                {
                    Bills diference = new Bills();
                    diference.Value = denomA.Value;
                    diference.NumberItems = denomB.NumberItems - denomA.NumberItems;

                    if(diference.NumberItems > 0) ListC.Add(diference);

                    isInListA = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!isInListA)
            {
                ListC.Add(denomB);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should show the `foreach` that you've tried...

Comment: ... and possibly the definition of the lists, as well... I can think of two possible routes, but it depends on how they've been instantiated.

Comment: When you say *difference*, do you mean create a 3rd list that holds the values that were in 1 list and not in the other?  Or are you planning on doing some subtraction somewhere?  Because I'm confused where you got `Denom:20NumberItems:3` for `ListC`.  I can see where `Denom:50 NumberItems:2` came from because it exists in `ListB` and not `ListA`

Comment: Do you *always* subtract `ListA` from `ListB`? Is it possible that a denomination in `ListA` will ever have a higher number than the same denomination in `ListB`?

Comment: i mean, if the Denom exists in the ListA get the NumberItems difference (ListB.NumberItems - ListA.NumberItems) and if the Value exists in ListB and not in ListA, get the Item and put in ListC

Comment: ListA will always have the same or smaller NumberItems than ListB

Comment: For the definition of the lists, a third party DLL give me the lists:
      ListA = ECRMCashIn.CounterDivertCassette();

Comment: what if one list contains multiple items of the same denomination? there are too many unanswered questions for anyone to give you a reponse. you should show the implementation you have that works, which you want to convert to linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a *left outer join* (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)). Something like this:

```
var listC = from b in listB join a in listA on b.Denom equals a.Denom into temp
    from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Bills() { Denom = b.Denom, NumberItems = t != null ? b.NumberItems - t.NumberItems : b.NumberItems };
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pCWf84)

The idea is to join `listB` with `listA` where `Denom` is equal, and then select a new `Bills` item with the same `Denom` and either the difference in `NumberItems` or (if it doesn't exist in `listB`, just the `NumberItems` from `listB`.

Now it appears from your edit that you want to remove items where `NumberItems` == 0, that can be easily done with a `Where` clause:

```
listC = listC.Where(c => c.NumberItems > 0);
```